Which is the fastest way to load all the values of an Xarray Dataset of dimension (43393, 654400) into a numpy array?
I am working with atmospheric data that is stored in Xarray Datasets.
However, when I try to load the numerical values into numpy arrays to compute further operations, it takes a lot of time :(
In fact, the JupyterNotebook kernel always dies before finishing - I guess due to lack of space, but I have 256 GB of memory.
Does anyone know how can I do it more efficiently?
Thanks!
I have tried loading the data year by year, but it is still too slow and does not finish due to lack of storage.
Here is the code:
#################################
# CATALOG LOAD
################################
link = "link to intake catalog"
cat = intake.open_catalog(link)

cat1 = "28kmresolution"
cat2 = "2D_1h_native_data"

ds = cat.IFS[cat1][cat2]


#################################
# VARIABLE LOAD
################################
wind_speed = np.sqrt(ds['10u']**2 + ds['10v']**2)   # 10m above surface wind speed 

#################################
# VARIABLE INFORMATION
################################
print(wind_speed.shape)                             # (43393, 654400)
print(type(ws))                                     #<class 'xarray.core.dataarray.DataArray'>
GigaBytes = int(round(ws.nbytes/1e9))
print(GigaBytes)                                    # 227 GB


#################################
# LOAD THE VALUES INTO NUMPY ARRAY
################################
ws2023 = ws.sel(time = "2023")
print(ws2023.shape)                                 # (8670, 654400)

#----------------------------------
# And here is when the Kernel shuts down
wind_speed_values = ws2023.values                  




If wind_speed is in RAM then it make sense for the kernel to shutdown because of the lack of memory space. The OS needs at least 1-3 GB and 227+23=250 GB so >98% of your RAM is used. If you do not have storage space either, then there is no solution besides using smaller data. You certainly have bitten off more than you can chew. If you store data on the disk, then things will be slow. There is no free lunch. However, you can try to compute things as locally as possibly for chunks to be in RAM and the rest on the disk loaded as few times as possible.
